# Multivariable calculus, level curves

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametrization

> Let $$f(x,y) = 3x^2 + 4xy + 3y^2$$ for all $(x,y)$ in $R^2$. To study f it can be useful to implement the variable substitution $$u = x + y \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad v= x-y .$$
>
> a) Sketch some of the level curves of $f$.
> b) Sketch the graph of $f$.
> c) Determine a parametrisation of the curve that is given by the intersection of $f$ and the plane with equation $z=x+3y$.

So I'm stuck here on the first assignment. It feels like every way I twist and turn it I still end up with some unwanted $y$'s on the wrong side, it was a while since doing calculus so I'm not really used to screwing around with these kind of things.

I tried using $(x+y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2$ and then I end up with $x^2 + y^2 + u^2 = c$ (using the u-substitution) but I don't know where to go from there. Any help at all greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Just write $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ and substitute in the formula defining $f$.

Comment: Thanks chap, I tried but I didn't get further than I wrote ($x^2 + y^2 + u^2 = c$) how can I utilize it further?

Comment: That's not solving for $u, v$ in terms of $x, y$. I've written out the formulas for $x$ and $y$ given by solving the linear system in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Note that a level curve is represented by the equation:
$$
3x^2+4xy+3y^2=k
$$
That is an [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Cartesian_coordinates) with center in the origin because $B^2-4AC= (4)^2-4\cdot(3)\cdot(3)<0$.

Now use the [Principal axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_axis_theorem) to find the axis of the ellipse and take some  point $P=(x_P,y_P)$ on these axis to find some level curve.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** We can solve simultaneously for $u, v$ in terms of $x, y$:
$$x = \tfrac{1}{2}(u + v), \qquad y = \tfrac{1}{2}(u - v).$$
Substituting these expressions in $f(x, y)$ gives a formula $f(x(u, v), y(u, v))$ for $f$ in the coordinates $u, v$.

Comment: Oh, that's neat. I ended up with $2u^2+2v^2=c$, I reckon that's correct(?). So, how do I go from here, do I write out the level curves of f in terms of u and v instead of x and y?

Comment: Based on the wording, I'd guess you're supposed to write out the level curves in terms of $x, y$.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it now - thanks alot mate! :)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful!